# There are 6 cards with letters a, c, e, i, m, n in a box. Somebody picks cards in a random order.What is the probability of getting the word “cinema”?

Tags: probability

This is a probability question.

There are 6 cards with letters a, c, e, i, m, n in a box. Somebody picks cards in a
random order. What is the probability of getting the
word “cinema”?

Don't solve it for me. I just need a hint or two. If you know the theory (theorem) required to solve the question please write it to me. Thank you.

Regards
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First consider the total number of ways to pick these letters - how many ways can you pick the first? then the second? and so on.

Now if the order of the final 6 letters are to spell the word "cinema", how many choices do you have for the first letter? the second? continue this way and you have the total number of ways you can pick the 6 letters such that they spell "cinema".

And so what is the required probability?

Answer (score 2):

One of all possible permutations.